# ALTERNATIVE METHODS To bucketing data into specified groups in R

Tags: r

THIS QUESTION IS NOT DUPLICATE OF 'CUT' FUNCTION RELATED POSTS!! 
PLEASE NOTE I USED CUT FUNCTION, BUT I EXPECT USERS AND EXPERTS TO SUGGEST ME ALTERNATIVES, CUT FUNCTION I AM NOT LOOKING AS SOLUTION.

For a dataset as shown below, I want to create groups such as

- group1: Dia values 891 to 889
- group2: Dia values 898.99 to 880
- group3: Dia values 879.99 to 870
- group4: Dia values 869.99 to 860
- group5: Dia values 859.99 to 850
- group6: Dia values 849.99 to 840
- group7: all values of Dia less than 839.99

I already used the below, I am looking for alternative methods, something using 'dplyr' like package, which could create bucketed groups.

Desired output:

```
CWC    WS   Dia    DiaBkt
US328   L   890.7   Group1
US328   L   890.64  Group1
US328   L   890.62  Group1
US328   L   849.18  Group6
US328   L   848.72  Group6
US328   L   846.52  Group6
```

And so forth.

Data and work:

```
# Read the below table after copying it into clipboard
dat <- read.table("clipboard", header=TRUE)

# I already used the below, I am looking for alternative methods, something using 'dplyr' like package

dat$DiaBukt <- cut(dat$Dia, breaks = c(Inf, 888.00, 880.00, 870.00, 860.00, 850.00, 840.00, -Inf), labels = c("Gruop0", "Gruop1", "Gruop2", "Gruop3", "Gruop4", "Gruop5", "Gruop6"), right=FALSE)

CWC WS  Dia
US328   L   890.7
US328   L   890.64
US328   L   890.62
US328   L   890.58
US328   L   890.52
US328   L   890.5
US328   L   890.48
US328   L   890.46
US328   L   890.44
US328   L   890.42
US328   L   890.4
US328   L   890.38
US328   L   890.34
US328   L   890.32
US328   L   890.3
US328   L   890.28
US328   L   890.26
US328   L   890.22
US328   L   890.2
US328   L   890.18
US328   L   890.14
US328   L   890.1
US328   L   890.08
US328   L   890.06
US328   L   890.04
US328   L   890.02
US328   L   889.96
US328   L   889.94
US328   L   889.92
US328   L   889.88
US328   L   889.86
US328   L   889.84
US328   L   889.8
US328   L   889.78
US328   L   889.76
US328   L   889.74
US328   L   889.7
US328   L   889.68
US328   L   889.66
US328   L   889.62
US328   L   889.6
US328   L   889.58
US328   L   889.56
US328   L   889.52
US328   L   889.44
US328   L   889.34
US328   L   889.06
US328   L   889.02
US328   L   889
US328   L   888.7
US328   L   884.93
US328   L   884.59
US328   L   884.15
US328   L   883.59
US328   L   881.02
US328   L   880.96
US328   L   880.84
US328   L   880.82
US328   L   853.54
US328   L   852.59
US328   L   852.45
US328   L   852.24
US328   L   852.14
US328   L   852.08
US328   L   852.06
US328   L   852.05
US328   L   852.04
US328   L   852.01
US328   L   852
US328   L   851.98
US328   L   851.97
US328   L   851.95
US328   L   851.94
US328   L   851.92
US328   L   851.9
US328   L   851.86
US328   L   851.84
US328   L   851.83
US328   L   851.82
US328   L   851.81
US328   L   851.73
US328   L   851.71
US328   L   851.68
US328   L   851.67
US328   L   851.64
US328   L   851.62
US328   L   851.57
US328   L   851.53
US328   L   851.52
US328   L   851.46
US328   L   851.43
US328   L   851.42
US328   L   851.38
US328   L   851.33
US328   L   851.32
US328   L   851.23
US328   L   851.22
US328   L   851.21
US328   L   851.18
US328   L   851.15
US328   L   850.95
US328   L   850.87
US328   L   850.81
US328   L   850.75
US328   L   850.71
US328   L   850.62
US328   L   850.59
US328   L   850.53
US328   L   850.49
US328   L   850.47
US328   L   850.46
US328   L   850.43
US328   L   850.35
US328   L   850.3
US328   L   850.27
US328   L   850.25
US328   L   850.19
US328   L   849.88
US328   L   849.87
US328   L   849.76
US328   L   849.66
US328   L   849.6
US328   L   849.48
US328   L   849.44
US328   L   849.4
US328   L   849.28
US328   L   849.24
US328   L   849.2
US328   L   849.18
US328   L   848.72
US328   L   846.52
US328   L   846.4
US328   L   846.36
US328   L   846.34
US328   L   846.32
US328   L   846.28
US328   L   846.26
US328   L   846.24
US328   L   846.22
US328   L   846.2
US328   L   846.18
US328   L   846.14
US328   L   846.08
US328   L   846.06
US328   L   846.04
US328   L   846.02
US328   L   846
US328   L   845.98
US328   L   845.96
US328   L   845.94
US328   L   845.92
US328   L   845.88
US328   L   845.86
US328   L   845.84
US328   L   845.82
US328   L   845.8
US328   L   845.76
US328   L   845.74
US328   L   845.64
US328   L   845.54
US328   L   845.48
US328   L   845.4
US328   L   845.26
US328   L   845.18
US328   L   845.14
US328   L   845.06
US328   L   845
US328   L   844.96
US328   L   844.86
US328   L   844.84
US328   L   844.78
US328   L   844.76
US328   L   844.66
US328   L   844.64
US328   L   844.58
US328   L   844.56
US328   L   844.52
US328   L   844.4
US328   L   844.36
US328   L   844.32
US328   L   844.3
US328   L   844.26
US328   L   843.98
US328   L   843.96
US328   L   843.86
US328   L   843.8
US328   L   843.78
US328   L   843.76
US328   L   843.66
US328   L   843.62
US328   L   843.6
US328   L   843.56
US328   L   843.54
US328   L   843.48
US328   L   843.46
US328   L   843.44
US328   L   843.4
US328   L   843.38
US328   L   843.34
US328   L   843.32
US328   L   843.28
US328   L   843.26
US328   L   843.24
US328   L   843.22
US328   L   843.2
US328   L   843.18
US328   L   843.16
US328   L   843.14
US328   L   843.12
US328   L   843.08
US328   L   843.06
US328   L   843.04
US328   L   843.02
US328   L   843
US328   L   842.98
US328   L   842.94
US328   L   842.92
US328   L   842.9
US328   L   842.88
US328   L   842.86
US328   L   842.84
US328   L   842.82
US328   L   842.8
US328   L   842.78
US328   L   842.76
US328   L   842.74
US328   L   842.72
US328   L   842.7
US328   L   842.68
US328   L   842.66
US328   L   842.64
US328   L   842.62
US328   L   842.58
US328   L   842.56
US328   L   842.54
US328   L   842.52
US328   L   842.5
US328   L   842.48
US328   L   842.46
US328   L   842.42
US328   L   842.4
US328   L   842.36
US328   L   842.32
US328   L   842.26
US328   L   842.22
US328   L   842.2
US328   L   842.18
US328   L   842.16
US328   L   842.14
US328   L   842.12
US328   L   842.08
US328   L   842.06
US328   L   842.04
US328   L   842.02
US328   L   842
US328   L   841.98
US328   L   841.94
US328   L   841.92
US328   L   841.78
US328   L   841.7
US328   L   841.66
US328   L   841.62
US328   L   841.6
US328   L   841.56
US328   L   841.54
US328   L   841.52
US328   L   841.5
US328   L   841.48
US328   L   841.46
US328   L   841.4
US328   L   841.36
US328   L   841.34
US328   L   841.32
US328   L   841.3
US328   L   841.28
US328   L   841.24
US328   L   841.22
US328   L   841.18
US328   L   841.16
US328   L   841.14
US328   L   841.12
US328   L   841.08
US328   L   841.06
US328   L   841.04
US328   L   841
US328   L   840.98
US328   L   840.96
US328   L   840.94
US328   L   840.92
US328   L   840.9
US328   L   840.86
US328   L   840.84
US328   L   840.8
US328   L   840.78
US328   L   840.74
US328   L   840.72
US328   L   840.7
US328   L   840.64
US328   L   840.58
US328   L   840.54
US328   L   840.5
US328   L   840.48
US328   L   840.44
US328   L   840.36
US328   L   840.3
US328   L   840.24
US328   L   840.2
US328   L   840.1
US328   L   840.06
US328   L   839.96
US328   L   839.94
US328   L   839.9
US328   L   839.84
US328   L   839.8
US328   L   839.78
US328   L   839.76
US328   L   839.72
US328   L   839.7
US328   L   839.66
US328   L   839.64
US328   L   839.62
US328   L   839.6
US328   L   839.58
US328   L   839.54
US328   L   839.4
US328   R   889.64
US328   R   889.54
US328   R   889.46
US328   R   889.42
US328   R   889.38
US328   R   889.36
US328   R   889.32
US328   R   889.3
US328   R   889.28
US328   R   889.26
US328   R   889.24
US328   R   889.22
US328   R   889.2
US328   R   889.18
US328   R   889.16
US328   R   889.14
US328   R   889.1
US328   R   889.08
US328   R   889.04
US328   R   888.98
US328   R   888.96
US328   R   888.92
US328   R   888.9
US328   R   888.88
US328   R   888.86
US328   R   888.84
US328   R   888.78
US328   R   888.76
US328   R   888.74
US328   R   888.72
US328   R   888.66
US328   R   888.64
US328   R   888.6
US328   R   888.58
US328   R   888.56
US328   R   888.52
US328   R   888.5
US328   R   888.46
US328   R   888.44
US328   R   888.36
US328   R   888.34
US328   R   885.82
US328   R   885.38
US328   R   885.14
US328   R   885.04
US328   R   884.94
US328   R   884.64
US328   R   884.62
US328   R   884.6
US328   R   884.46
US328   R   884.38
US328   R   884.3
US328   R   884.26
US328   R   884.16
US328   R   883.9
US328   R   883.32
US328   R   854.24
US328   R   854.08
US328   R   854
US328   R   853.9
US328   R   853.78
US328   R   853.74
US328   R   853.6
US328   R   853.48
US328   R   853.42
US328   R   853.36
US328   R   853.2
US328   R   853.18
US328   R   853.14
US328   R   853.1
US328   R   853.08
US328   R   853.02
US328   R   853
US328   R   852.98
US328   R   852.82
US328   R   852.78
US328   R   852.62
US328   R   852.5
US328   R   852.44
US328   R   852.4
US328   R   852.38
US328   R   852.34
US328   R   852.26
US328   R   852.2
US328   R   852.18
US328   R   851.96
US328   R   851.88
US328   R   851.74
US328   R   851.72
US328   R   851.58
US328   R   851.24
US328   R   851.02
US328   R   850.94
US328   R   850.92
US328   R   850.86
US328   R   850.84
US328   R   850.76
US328   R   850.64
US328   R   850.58
US328   R   850.52
US328   R   850.5
US328   R   850.44
US328   R   850.22
US328   R   850.16
US328   R   850.14
US328   R   850
US328   R   849.8
US328   R   849.78
US328   R   849.74
US328   R   849.72
US328   R   849.68
US328   R   849.38
US328   R   849.26
US328   R   846.1
US328   R   845.9
US328   R   845.78
US328   R   845.72
US328   R   845.7
US328   R   845.68
US328   R   845.66
US328   R   845.6
US328   R   845.56
US328   R   845.52
US328   R   845.5
US328   R   845.44
US328   R   845.42
US328   R   845.38
US328   R   845.36
US328   R   845.32
US328   R   845.24
US328   R   844.98
US328   R   844.94
US328   R   844.9
US328   R   844.62
US328   R   844.42
US328   R   844.38
US328   R   844.34
US328   R   844.22
US328   R   844.2
US328   R   844.16
US328   R   844.14
US328   R   844.08
US328   R   843.94
US328   R   843.74
US328   R   843.64
US328   R   843.42
US328   R   843.36
US328   R   842.6
US328   R   842.38
US328   R   842.34
US328   R   842.3
US328   R   842.28
US328   R   842.24
US328   R   842.1
US328   R   841.9
US328   R   841.88
US328   R   841.86
US328   R   841.84
US328   R   841.82
US328   R   841.8
US328   R   841.76
US328   R   841.74
US328   R   841.68
US328   R   841.44
US328   R   841.42
US328   R   841.38
US328   R   841.26
US328   R   841.1
US328   R   840.82
US328   R   840.76
US328   R   840.18
US328   R   840.14
US328   R   840.08
US328   R   839.52
US328   R   839.48
US328   R   839.28
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question:

```
cut(dat$Dia, breaks = c(-Inf, 840, 850, 860, 870, 880. 890), right=FALSE)
```

Should do the job.

How you used cut, `Dia` was cut into 6 equally sized Intervalls, determined by the range of `Dia`.
You should specify in your case the endpoints of the interval, which is done in the sample code.

The parameter `right` determines, wether the interval's right border is opened or closed.

Comment: would it consider `'L' and 'R' values of WS` ??

Comment: what do you mean by consider??
It would just group the `Dia` values, maybe you can give an example of what is you expected outcome.

Comment: I mean Dia groups for only 'L' and similarly, Dia groups only for 'R' of WS. So there will be two groups of WS also. and then Cut function to be applied.

Comment: As I do not know what you need it for at the end, my cut `dia` first and the take a look at this: `help("interaction")` this gives you combinations of two factors.